# Function referenced in section `.text' of ...: defined in discarded section `.text'

Tags: gcc, mingw

I get an error from `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` (please see subject) when linking a c-source file using CMake containing a call to `Sleep()`. I would like to know the reason for this in order to solve the problem.

This is the invocation of the compiler:

```
/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc   -g @CMakeFiles/MQTTAsync_publish.dir/includes_C.rsp   -o CMakeFiles/MQTTAsync_publish.dir/src/samples/MQTTAsync_publish.c.obj   -c /tmp/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.c/src/samples/MQTTAsync_publish.c
```

The archiver:

```
/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ar cr CMakeFiles/MQTTAsync_publish.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles/MQTTAsync_publish.dir/objects1.rsp
```

The linker:

```
/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc  -g  -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup -static-libgcc -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles/MQTTAsync_publish.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o MQTTAsync_publish.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libMQTTAsync_publish.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles/MQTTAsync_publish.dir/linklibs.rsp
`_Sleep' referenced in section `.text' of CMakeFiles/MQTTAsync_publish.dir/objects.a(MQTTAsync_publish.c.obj): defined in discarded section `.text' of /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9-win32/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libkernel32.a(libkernel32s01140.o)
```

These are the contents of the linker response file:

```
 libpaho-mqtt3a.dll.a -lpthread -lws2_32 -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
```

**Minimal stripped down working sample:**

main.c:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    Sleep(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler/Linker call:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -static-libgcc -lpthread -lws2_32 -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -o main.exe main.c
```

No problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unbelievable, I just had to `#include <windows.h>` in the C file mentioned originally and it linked without any hassle.

Comment: Why is it unbelievable? By omitting `<windows.h>`, you neglected to inform the compiler that `Sleep()` is a `__stdcall` function, and thus its publicly exposed name is actually `Sleep@4()`. You simply must _never_ neglect to include `<windows.h>`, when you use Windows API functions, because the majority of them are `__stdcall`, and the compiler _needs_ to know this.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! That makes things a lot clearer.

Comment: So far I did a lot more development on Linux/Unix systems and it seems that function calling conventions, function name mangling in shared libraries, etc. are not that a big deal here.

Comment: `__stdcall` is specific to MS-Windows, (and the majority of Windows API functions use it). However, even if you develop primarily for Linux, that doesn't excuse you from including the requisite header files; that's a programming error regardless. You could, of course, just use `sleep()`, which is now implemented for MinGW from mingwrt-3.21.1 onwards, (but _not_ in the broken 4.x releases), _provided_ you include `<unistd.h>`.

Comment: You are right. I was expecting a compiler warning in that case (`implicit declaration of function`). But, as warnings were not turned on (`-Wall`), it was the linker that gave me an error.